# Build Grub2 EFI for Ubuntu from nothing

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub, efi

After installing Ubuntu, I deleted the EFI partition. I would like to rebuild that partition, I don't want to perform data recovery. I have recreated a partition of a similar size there at SDA2  FAT32, and given it the EFI system flag. I went to 10 websites to make the EFI Grub work and followed their instructions, but all failed. Tried Boot-Repair live and also from booted inside the Ubuntu as well. Tried a lot. What specific steps have you personally used and succeeded with under these same circumstances? Thanks people

Comment: You have to use Boot-Repair's advanced mode & do a total reinstall of grub.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  Default often is just a update of grub menu. Or use Supergrub or Resutux to boot & totally reinstall grub from inside your install. Or chroot into install & reinstall grub. https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/   chroot with UEFI, LVM, encryption on NVMe drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349833&p=13602088#post13602088

Comment: Thank you, I have already performed all of those, and none of them worked. I have been using all of those utilities for years. Next suggestion?

Comment: If full reinstall of grub does not work, then something else is wrong. Post link to Summary Report from Boot-Repair. You can use Ubuntu live installer and download latest version using the ppa.  What version of Ubuntu? What brand/model system?

Comment: Thank you for both suggestions, oldfred. I am happy to post the summary report link for you. Which settings for boot repair would you recommend? There are many ways to use it. I see up there you recommended the Boot Repair Advanced Mode, but which settings should I use?

Comment: I thought you said you ran Boot-Repair? But I was suggesting that you just run the Summary Report & post link. Then we can see details and suggest what to do. Otherwise we are just shooting in the dark and may make things worse.

Comment: I did say I ran boot repair. I have been using boot repair for years, the live and the installed versions. I also said there are 2 modes, the Recommended, and the Advanced. The Advanced has many options. If you would like me to post the Summary Report after using Boot Repair, I asked which mode and options do you want me to use, to generate the Summary Report. I have deleted the efi partition files again, so we are starting from scratch. The ball is in your court.

Comment: The Summary Report is just a report, you do not have to select any advanced options. The advanced options are for updates and only by seeing report can we suggest which options may be best.

Comment: If there is someone else out there who can say what settings I could start with, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: See Also: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2465313&p=14050717#post14050717

Comment: Oldfred a lot of the internet is a wastebasket of useless posts. Don't add to it, do everyone a favor and get out of this forum. Men are working.